# glLineStipple() and waving patterns

Tags: opengl

I am using glLineStipple() to make pattern on lines with OpenGL 2.0. It is ok but patterns aren't constant they are always waving.

Is there any way to solve this problem with old OpenGL functions or shaders?

I am using vtk's mapper and its vertex and fragment shaders

```
/*=========================================================================

  Program:   Visualization Toolkit
  Module:    vtkglPolyDataVSNoLighting.glsl

  Copyright (c) Ken Martin, Will Schroeder, Bill Lorensen
  All rights reserved.
  See Copyright.txt or http://www.kitware.com/Copyright.htm for details.

     This software is distributed WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even
     the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR
     PURPOSE.  See the above copyright notice for more information.

=========================================================================*/
// The following line handle system declarations such a
// default precisions, or defining precisions to null
//VTK::System::Dec

// all variables that represent positions or directions have a suffix
// indicating the coordinate system they are in. The possible values are
// MC - Model Coordinates
// WC - WC world coordinates
// VC - View Coordinates
// DC - Display Coordinates
attribute vec4 vertexMC;

// material property values
//VTK::Color::Dec

// camera and actor matrix values
uniform mat4 MCVCMatrix;  // combined Model to View transform
uniform mat4 VCDCMatrix;  // the camera's projection matrix

// Texture coordinates
//VTK::TCoord::Dec

void main()
{
  //VTK::Color::Impl

  //VTK::TCoord::Impl

  gl_Position = VCDCMatrix * MCVCMatrix * vertexMC;
}


/*=========================================================================

  Program:   Visualization Toolkit
  Module:    vtkglPolyDataFSNoLighting.glsl

  Copyright (c) Ken Martin, Will Schroeder, Bill Lorensen
  All rights reserved.
  See Copyright.txt or http://www.kitware.com/Copyright.htm for details.

     This software is distributed WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even
     the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR
     PURPOSE.  See the above copyright notice for more information.

=========================================================================*/

// The following line handle system declarations such a
// default precisions, or defining precisions to null
//VTK::System::Dec

varying vec4 fcolor;

// Texture coordinates
//VTK::TCoord::Dec

// material property values
uniform float opacityUniform; // the fragment opacity
uniform vec3 ambientColorUniform; // intensity weighted color
uniform vec3 diffuseColorUniform; // intensity weighted color

//VTK::Color::Dec

// picking support
//VTK::Picking::Dec

// Depth Peeling Support
//VTK::DepthPeeling::Dec

void main()
{
  vec3 ambientColor = ambientColorUniform;
vec3 diffuseColor = diffuseColorUniform;
float opacity = opacityUniform;
  // Note that the above will always define vec3 ambientColor, vec3 diffuseColor and float opacity

  gl_FragColor =  vec4(ambientColor + diffuseColor, opacity);
  //VTK::TCoord::Impl

  if (gl_FragColor.a <= 0.0)
    {
    discard;
    }

  //VTK::DepthPeeling::Impl

  //VTK::Picking::Impl

}
```

and It's drawing like that

```
................
    glLineStipple(2, 0x00FF);
    glEnable(GL_LINE_STIPPLE);
      glMultiDrawElements(GL_LINE_STRIP,
                        (GLsizei *)(&this->Lines.elementsArray[0]),
                        GL_UNSIGNED_INT,
                        reinterpret_cast<const GLvoid **>(&(this->Lines.offsetArray[0])),
                        (GLsizei)this->Lines.offsetArray.size());

    glDisable(GL_LINE_STIPPLE);
................
```

Comment: can we see the code you wrote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classic line stipple is done during rasterization by treating the stipple pattern as a bit-mask and bitwise ANDing with raster coordinates.  This is why it shimmers as you move windows on the screen, camera viewpoints, etc.

A better approach on modern hardware is to implement stipple using a 1-D texture as an alpha mask, with the GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S set to GL_REPEAT and setting the texture coordinates at each point on the line per the length of that segment.  You may still get potential discontinuities at mipmap boundaries, but it shouldn't be nearly as bad.  Perspective correct interpolation as is performed between vertex and fragment shaders should behave much better than classical stippling.

Comment: hi Drew, I am beginner of opengl is there any example how to implement it?

Comment: Hi Veysel.  I found the following discussion on the OpenGL.org forums that may help some:  https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/184862-How-to-draw-a-line-stipple-with-ES-2-0

Comment: Thank you Drew, before draw function do I set gl function for GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S and GL_REPEAT also u_sampler is pattern like 0x00FF isnt it?

Comment: @Veysel: Depends on what you're trying to achieve.  The way I described would preserve the stipple spacing across lines of different lengths.  You could just use tex coords of 0 and 1 at the ends and you'd get a stipple that stretched to fit the segment length.  As you guessed, you put the stipple pattern in the texture data itself--the sampler just pulls out the texture value at the specified coordinate.